# Unable to upload a file to box (file storage system)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am completely new to authentication concepts. The goal is to upload files to box using `box-node-sdk` (a node pacakge), I was advised to do Oauth with JWT to box in-order to manage my application data on box. But I keep keep getting the following error

> err: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Following is the code in my back-end. Please help me in learning and understanding this.
All my keys are coming from `env`.

```js
var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');
var sdk = new BoxSDK({
    clientID: process.env.BOX_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.BOX_CLIENT_SECRET,
    appAuth: {
        keyID: process.env.BOX_PUBLIC_KEY_ID,
        privateKey: process.env.BOX_PRIVATE_KEY,
        passphrase: process.env.BOX_PASSPHRASE,
        expirationTime: 60,
        verifyTimestamp: false,
    },
    enterpriseID: process.env.BOX_ENTERPRISE_ID
});

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
// Get an app user client
var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('user', process.env.BOX_APP_USER_ID);
var fileData = fs.createReadStream('hello_world.png')
client.files.uploadFile('71331215581', 'hello_world.png', fileData,
    function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);
        }
    })
```

Comment: I've updated the formatting on your question, you should now be able to see that your example is incomplete as the last function call is unclosed. Is this your full code or did you just miss some braces?

Comment: Thanks for formatting, the code is correct in my local, I couldn't copy it completely.